# Get json from url by string indice Flask

Tags: python, flask

Url : 127.0.0.1:5000/mywebservice?&list=hello&list=world&dict={"type":"mail","subject":"Hello","content":"hello world"}

I am trying to get json from the url 
list=request.args.getlist(list) allow me to get list like this way list[0] =hello ,list[1] =world

the URL will be like that:

---

Url : 127.0.0.1:5000/mywebservice&list=hello&list=world&dict[type]=mail&dict[subject]=Hello&dic[content]=hello world

---

Is there a way that allows me to get the dictionary like this way?

Expected result:

```
dic=request.args.get(dict)

var= dic['type']

print(var)====> mail
```

however:

```
dic = request.args.get(dict)
var = dic['type']
print(var) : Exception
```

PS: request.json doesn't have access to the url and there is not

```
 dic = request.args.getjson(dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly `dict` from URL will have serialized JSON. You need to use `json` package to de-serialize it.

```py
import json


url_dict = request.args.get('dict')
dic = json.loads(url_dict)
print (dic['type'])
```

Comment: I'm working like that now, I'm looking for a way to work with the second example of the url: 127.0.0.1:5000/mywebservice&list=hello&list=world&dict[type]=mail&dict[subject]=Hello&dic[content]=hello world

Comment: If you would like to do it that way you will lose ability to get query params info with just one var. Usually people don't prefer that.